# Arch Linux Gnome 3 slow login -> desktop transition and 2 gnome-sessions when booting up

Tags: arch-linux, gnome3

I have a fresh install of Arch Linux using Gnome 3 as my Desktop Environment. I also installed nvidia proprietary drivers for my GTX 970. The problem i'm facing is that after my log-in screen pops up and i enter my credentials, it takes about 40 seconds to reach my desktop and during this "down time" my monitor enters a power saving state. I get to my desktop and if i open up a terminal and run `ps -e | grep -E "(gnome|gdm)"`, I get the following output

```
  313 ?        00:00:00 gdm
  434 ?        00:00:00 gdm-session-wor
  437 tty1     00:00:00 gdm-x-session
  454 tty1     00:00:00 gnome-session
  470 tty1     00:00:00 gnome-settings-
  490 tty1     00:00:01 gnome-shell
  639 ?        00:00:00 gdm-session-wor
  649 ?        00:00:00 gnome-keyring-d
  663 tty2     00:00:00 gdm-x-session
  670 tty2     00:00:00 gnome-session
  696 tty2     00:00:00 gnome-settings-
  742 tty2     00:00:12 gnome-shell
  756 tty2     00:00:00 gnome-shell-cal
 1165 tty2     00:00:00 gnome-terminal-
 1168 tty2     00:00:00 gnome-pty-helpe
```

From this output I get that somehow, gnome-session starts up on 2 different ttys. If I switch to tty1, Same story as with logging in. My monitor goes to power saving, I wait aprox 40 seconds and then I get the login screen.

I have no idea where to start looking for the problem.

I installed gnome using `pacman -S gnome`, chose the `mesa-libgl` library and after i got to the desktop environment, i downloaded nvidia proprietary drivers, blacklisted nouveau and ran the .run nvidia file.

Has anyone encountered this situation? Do you have any idea what can I do? which log fiels should I open up or configs to change?

Thanks

Comment: you might try display mangers other than gdm ? (I think after you install another display manager you have to disable gdm.service and enable whatever display manager you installed)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the solution.  However, I have the same issue with Arch Linux and it is a known gdm bug, see GNOME Bugzilla – Bug 747339.
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=747339